# partition function therm in the derivation of log likelihood in RBM?

Tags: machine-learning, restricted-boltzmann-machine

In the following derivation when we take derivative of second term why the summation is only over h although it should be be over v and h because we are dealing with Z.
[image]

Comment: Comparison to the third line indicates it's a typographical error.

Comment: Does this summation is over the number of hidden nodes in one layer or it is summation over possible values of h and v which are 0 and 1 for RBM